# Function that generates new structure data type and returns pointer

Tags: pointers, struct, malloc, typedef

I am trying to make a program, which creates a new data type data_t of a structure. A function then allocates memory for the new data type on the heap. Then I want to change the values of number and name, how do I do this exactly? The way I tried it, does not seem to work:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    typedef struct{
      char name[32];
      int number;
      char checksum;
    }data_t;


    data_t *new_data(char *name, int number){

      data_t *ptr=malloc(sizeof(data_t));
      strcpy(ptr->name ,name)
      (ptr->number)=number;



      return ptr; 

    }
```

Comment: I would imagine that's because `data_t` is only defined within the scope of `new_data`, so the return type doesn't make sense from the point of view of outside the function. Move the struct definition outside.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the **struct** inside the function. It doesnt exist outside the function. Therefore the compiler shows unknown data type error.
Place the `typedef` outside the function.